# itunes connect move app to another account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to transfer app from itunes connect account to another by following this web site

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

but can't see the "Transfer App" menu item

[image]

Here are my roles

[image]

Any idea? Thanks, Michal

Comment: Maybe a dumb comment but, do you check "Criteria for Transferring an App" inside the document your linked?

Comment: Thank you Beto for comment. Yes I did.

Comment: I told you because maybe you can not fulfill all of the situation explain in this document. I have a situation with one of my apps and while the app stay in "rejected" status, I can not delete the app or transfer it.

Comment: Pretty unhelpful they don't give you the reason.

Answer (score 5):

**If you don't fulfill something or this, you can't see "Transfer App" option, get from Apple Documentation.
I hope help you.**

Criteria for Transferring an App

Before you transfer an app to another developer, ensure you’ve met the following criteria:

Make sure your accounts aren’t in a pending or changing state.
For example, make sure your account or your recipient’s account have agreed to any contract amendments that wait for approval and that any iAd App Network-related account information is up to date. See Viewing Contracts and Contract Status.

Make sure the app uses only technology and content that can be transferred.
No version of the app can use an iCloud entitlement.
No version of the app can use a Passbook entitlement.
The app can’t offer (or have previously offered) In-App Purchase subscriptions: auto-renewable, free, or non-renewing.
Make sure the app and any In-App Purchase products it offers have a status that supports transfers.

The app status can be one of the following, assuming that there is at least one approved version of the app: Ready for Sale, Prepare for Submission, Developer Removed From Sale, Invalid Binary, Developer Rejected, Rejected

In-App Purchase products can have one of the following statuses: Approved, Ready to Submit, Developer Removed From Sale, Rejected

Make sure that In-App Purchase product IDs on the app aren’t the same product IDs on any apps in the recipient’s account.
Make sure to turn off TestFlight beta testing for all prerelease versions of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the criteria you must meet to be able to transfer an app (and have the link show up in your iTunesConnect page), my experience was that the logged in user must be the Team Agent, which is whoever opened the account in the first place. No admins or app managers other than him will be able to see the link.

Here is a list of the criteria that you must meet to have the app be transferable: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Hope this helps.